# How do I make a pie radar chart in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I am trying to add a simple pie radar chart to a Google Sheets file for a college assignment. All I can find are simple pie charts.

Anyone know how to upgrade them to pie radar charts?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I believe there is no way. The options for types of chart are [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190718?hl=en) and pie radar is not one (though pie is and radar is).

You might want to consider [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts) though if so (a) any related Q may be better suited to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and (b) pie radar does not yet seem to be on offer in the [Chart Gallery](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) nor as a [community-contributed addition](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/more_charts).

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat crude, but it is possible to get a pie radar chart using a radar chart by making a circle of ~360 degrees, and setting each degree to a value based on what should be presented (at that point you are basically using the radar chart like an drawing tool).

Here's an example that shows this in action. It's made somewhat configurable by parameters throughout the table:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IavcC4gKVHPYwkJMGKxMmT8V0e_G-DWL2HSf9UJ9bVQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Pie Radar Chart of Impact Over Categories]